# Why doesn't my fontawesome icon render in my Next.js project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-awesome, html-rendering

I have a Next.js project where I am using fontawesome icons.

However, the icon does not show up on the web page. I even checked under inspect element and in the parent div and the icon element is not there.

Below is my _app.js file:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
config.autoAddCss = false

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

And below is my index.js file in the pages directory:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react"
import Head from 'next/head'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-brands fa-facebook-f" />
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Why isn't my icon rendering and how do I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to import icons into your project. That's why there is nothing showing. This is what your `index.js` should look like if using the free brands svg icons:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} />
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```